# Exchange a value within a nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby, nested

I have two nested arrays:

```
array1 = [[String_1, [String_2, [String_3.1, String_3.2, …]…]…] String_4…]
array2 = [[String_3.1, [String_3.1.1, String_3.1.2]], [String_3.2, [String_3.2.1, String_3.2.2]]]
```

I need to replace String_3.1 in `array1` with the matching part of `array2`:

```
[String_3.1, [String_3.1.1, String_3.1.2]]
```

This whole part should slip into the position of String_3.1 in `array1`.

I can't access the values to exchange by the `find_index` method because they are buried in the structure. I cannot flatten the array because the structure needs to stay intact.

I tried an approach with a recursive function:

```
def find_insert_point(array1)
  array1.each do |value|
    if value.is_a?(Array) == true
      find_insert_point(value)
      puts "#{value}" if value.class == String
    end
  end
end
```

This iterates through the entries without flattening the array. But I cannot use `map!` to alter the underlying real `array1` structure while iterating over `array2` data (not included in the code).

Is there any way to search for a specific index (e.g. by string) in a nested array with multiple levels and exchange a hit with other data (e.g. a sub-array)?

Comment: `String_3.1`, etc. are invalid. They must be something else. `1` is an invalid method name.

Comment: I suggest you edit to make `array1` and `array` valid arrays of strings, and show your desired output, so that readers who give answers can better show how the output is obtained.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use recursion to perform the substitution(s).

**Question**

Suppose we have:

```
array1 = [["cat", ["dog", ["cow", ["pig", "yak"], "owl"], "emu"], "hog"], "elk" ]
array2 = [["pig", ["ram", "ape"]], ["cow", ["bat", "fox"]]]
```

I assume:

- each element of `array2` has the form `[str, arr]` where `str` is a string and `arr` is an array (which may contain strings and/or arrays, with any level of nesting) and
- given a string `str`, you wish to replace every instance of `str` in `array1` or in any nested array in `array1` with `h2[str]`, where:

```
h2 = Hash[array2]
  #=> {"pig"=>["ram", "ape"], "cow"=>["bat", "fox"]}
```

**Code**

```
def replace_it(arr1, arr2, str)
  arr = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr1))
  recurse(arr, str, Hash[arr2][str])
  arr
end

def recurse(arr, str, replace)
  arr.size.times do |i|
    case arr[i]
    when Array then recurse(arr[i], str, replace)
    else arr[i] = [str, replace] if arr[i] == str
    end
  end
end
```

The methods [Marshal::dump](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal::dump](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load) are used to create a deep copy of `array1` so that it will not be mutated. If it is desired that `array1` be modified in place, the line containing those methods should be deleted and `arr` changed to `arr1` in the last two lines.

**Examples**

```
replace_it(array1, array2, "pig")
  #=> [["cat", ["dog", ["cow", [["pig", ["ram", "ape"]], "yak"], "owl"],
  #     "emu"], "hog"], "elk"] 

replace_it(array1, array2, "cow")
  #=> [["cat", ["dog", [["cow", ["bat", "fox"]], ["pig", "yak"],
  #     "owl"], "emu"], "hog"], "elk"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the substitution array is not deeply recursed, here you go:

```
array1 = [['String_1', 
          ['String_2', ['String_3.1', 'String_3.2']]],
           'String_4']
array2 = [['String_3.1', ['String_3.1.1', 'String_3.1.2']],
          ['String_3.2', ['String_3.2.1', 'String_3.2.2']]]

def subst arr, hsh 
  arr.map do |e| 
    Array === e ? subst(e, hsh) : hsh[e] ? [e, hsh[e]] : e
  end
end
subst array1, array2.to_h

#⇒ [
#  [0] [
#    [0] "String_1",
#    [1] [
#      [0] "String_2",
#      [1] [
#        [0] [
#          [0] "String_3.1",
#          [1] [
#            [0] "String_3.1.1",
#            [1] "String_3.1.2"
#          ]
#        ],
#        [1] [
#          [0] "String_3.2",
#          [1] [
#            [0] "String_3.2.1",
#            [1] "String_3.2.2"
#          ]
#        ]
#      ]
#    ]
#  ],
#  [1] "String_4"
# ]
```